# Does writing more data to disk consume more energy than writing less?

Tags: storage, power-consumption

As the title says, I am wondering if writing more data (i.e. larger files) to disk (e.g. Tablet SSDs) will consume more energy than smaller files.

My expected answer is "yes, because larger files take longer to write, hence need more energy". However, I am not sure if that is true.

If someone could shed some light (better with a link with more info from a reputable source), I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I think you are right, but the difference in the energies is probably so small it may be negligible.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you comparing energy of a single 10 Mb file to 10 individual 1 Mb files? In that case, there would be overhead for the smaller files, so they would probably consume more energy. Can you provide example numbers?

Comment: @EntangledLoops Thanks - I'll clarify. Pretend we have two identical SSDs. On 1, we write 10 2MB files, on the other we write 10 500KB files. Which case would consume more energy?

Comment: Okay, so on the first you have 10 * 2 Mb = 20 Mb, and the second you have 10 * 0.5 Mb = 5 Mb. My naive guess would be the first write, but I'm not sure what you're trying to get at here.

Comment: This may help: http://www.cse.psu.edu/~buu1/papers/ps/park-jsa11.pdf